# How to disconnect a signal

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3, libsigc++

I made a program to calculate the area and volume of shapes from a window. Everything works, except one thing regarding the use of `Gtk::Entry::signal_activate()`. In the following code:

```
  sigc::connection c = elongueur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); });
  switch (forme)
  {
  case 1: //carré
    cacheEntry();
    c.connected();
    labelForme.set_label(listeDeroulante.get_active_text());
    labelLongueur.set_label("longueur");
    break;
  case 2: //rectangle
    c.disconnect();
    elargeur.set_sensitive(true);
    labelForme.set_label(listeDeroulante.get_active_text());
    labelLongueur.set_label("longueur");
    labelLargeur.set_label("largeur");
    elongueur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { elargeur.grab_focus(); });
    elargeur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); });
    break;

 // ...
```

if I start with option case 2 everything works fine. If I go through case 1 and then case 2, pressing the enter key shifts the focus to the next `Gtk::Entry` but also launches the `calculation()` function, which I'm trying to avoid. I think the `Gtk::Entry::signal_activate()` handler is not disconnected after passing through case 1, but I don't know why since I am calling `sigc::connection::disconnect()` when entering case 2.

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add this header. See documentation from [sigc++](https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc%2B%2B/2.2/structsigc_1_1connection.html#a016094b53bafdc9ce593febb68cb00a5)

```
#include <sigc++/connection.h>
```

We have to disconnect signal and stop it

Declare in your own class

```
sigc::connection c;
```

then in your main programm we can do something like that

```
  switch (forme)
  {
  case 1: // carré
    cacheEntry();
    labelForme.set_label(listeDeroulante.get_active_text());
    labelLongueur.set_label("longueur");
    if (c.connected() == false)
    {
      c = elongueur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); });
    }
    break;
  case 2: // rectangle
    c.disconnect();//disconnected signal
    elargeur.set_sensitive(true);
    labelForme.set_label(listeDeroulante.get_active_text());
    labelLongueur.set_label("longueur");
    labelLargeur.set_label("largeur");
    elongueur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { elargeur.grab_focus(); });
    elargeur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); elargeur.signal_activate().emission_stop();/*stop signal*/ });
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small program to replicate your issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MyWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{

public:

    MyWindow()
    {
        m_btn1.signal_clicked().connect([this](){PerformAction1();});
        m_btn2.signal_clicked().connect([this](){PerformAction2();});
        m_btn1And2.signal_clicked().connect([this](){PerformActions1And2();});

        m_entryA.set_text("Entry A");
        m_entryB.set_text("Entry B");

        m_layout.attach(m_entryA, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        m_layout.attach(m_entryB, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        m_layout.attach(m_btn1, 0, 1, 2, 1);
        m_layout.attach(m_btn2, 0, 2, 2, 1);
        m_layout.attach(m_btn1And2, 0, 3, 2, 1);

        add(m_layout);
    }

    void Calcul()
    {
        std::cout << "calcul() called" << std::endl;
    }

    void PerformAction1()
    {
        // Add another handler here to amplify the problem:
        // m_signalEntryA = m_entryA.signal_activate().connect([this](){std::cout << "Action 0 : "; Calcul();});
        m_signalEntryA = m_entryA.signal_activate().connect([this](){std::cout << "Action 1 : "; Calcul();});

        // Works if you uncomment here:
        // m_signalEntryA.disconnect();
    }

    void PerformAction2()
    {
        m_signalEntryA = m_entryA.signal_activate().connect([this](){std::cout << "Action 2 : "; Calcul();});
        m_signalEntryA.disconnect();

        m_signalEntryA = m_entryA.signal_activate().connect([this](){m_entryB.grab_focus();});
        m_entryB.signal_activate().connect([this](){Calcul();});
    }

    void PerformActions1And2()
    {
        PerformAction1();
        PerformAction2();
    }

private:

    Gtk::Grid m_layout;
    Gtk::Entry m_entryA;
    Gtk::Entry m_entryB;
    Gtk::Button m_btn1{"Action 1"};
    Gtk::Button m_btn2{"Action 2"};
    Gtk::Button m_btn1And2{"Actions 1 and 2"};

    sigc::connection m_signalEntryA;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "so.question.q66320704");

    MyWindow window;
    window.show_all();

    return app->run(window);
}
```

This program has two cases, like yours that do the same fundamental operations on signals. You can activate the different scenarios using the buttons:

[image]

Running the program and clicking the buttons, then the Enter key, yields the following output:

- Action 1: `Action 1 : calcul() called`
- Action 2: Nothing
- Actions 1 and 2: `Action 1 : calcul() called`

From what I can see in this program, it seems that there is some sort of "stacking" in the signal connections. Uncommenting this line:

```cpp
m_signalEntryA = m_entryA.signal_activate().connect([this](){std::cout << "Action 0 : "; Calcul();});
```

yield the following output:

```
Action 0 : calcul() called
Action 1 : calcul() called
```

This was very surprising as this behavior is not documented in the [official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc%2B%2B/2.2/structsigc_1_1connection.html#a016094b53bafdc9ce593febb68cb00a5). Anyway, to solve your issue, it seems you have to call disconnect early, just before `break`.

```cpp
sigc::connection c = elongueur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); });
  switch (forme)
  {
  case 1: //carré
    cacheEntry();
    c.connected();
    labelForme.set_label(listeDeroulante.get_active_text());
    labelLongueur.set_label("longueur");
    c.disconnect(); // <-- Add this. The connection is no more needed.
    break;
  case 2: //rectangle
    c.disconnect();
    elargeur.set_sensitive(true);
    labelForme.set_label(listeDeroulante.get_active_text());
    labelLongueur.set_label("longueur");
    labelLargeur.set_label("largeur");
    elongueur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { elargeur.grab_focus(); });
    elargeur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); });
    break;
```

Note: My Gtkmm version is 3.22.

Comment: if you add output's function calculation() in a `std::cout` you have to add also `signal_activate().emission_stop()`. For example something like this `elargeur.signal_activate().connect([this]() { calcul(); elargeur.signal_activate().emission_stop(); });` otherwise it repeats `std::cout`many times. This means the signal is not totally deactivated

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure I understand. Are you still having your issue even when adding the extra `c.disconnect()` that I am suggesting?

Comment: yes still having issue. To solve it i added `emission_stop()` like i said before

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you add your own answer and accept it to help other members of the community who will encounter a similar issue.